# Pointcut annotation vs Final String

Tags: java, string, spring, aop, pointcut

So I'm studying tutorial on Spring AOP and when the concept of pointcut annotations was explained I thought "why not use final private String?". I've looked up but didn't find anything that might explain why use the overhead of pointcut?

with pointcut:

```
@Before("pointcutMethod()")
public void loggingAdvice(){
    System.out.println("loggin advice");
}

@Before("pointcutMethod()")
public void loggingAdviceTwo(){
    System.out.println("loggin advice2");
}

@Before("pointcutMethod() || secondPointcutMethod()")
public void loggingAdviceTree(){
    System.out.println("loggin advice3");
}

@Pointcut("execution(public * get*())")
public void pointcutMethod(){}

 @Pointcut("within(shapes.Circle)")
public void secondPointcutMethod(){}
```

and with private final String:

```
private static final String EXECUTION_PUBLIC_GET = "execution(public * get*())";
private static final String WITHIN_SHAPES_CIRCLE = "within(shapes.Circle)";
private static final String OR = " || ";

@Before(EXECUTION_PUBLIC_GET)
public void loggingAdvice(){
    System.out.println("loggin advice");
}


@Before(EXECUTION_PUBLIC_GET)
public void loggingAdviceTwo(){
    System.out.println("loggin advice2");
}

@Before(EXECUTION_PUBLIC_GET + OR + WITHIN_SHAPES_CIRCLE)
public void loggingAdviceTree(){
    System.out.println("loggin advice3");
```

edit: I was pointed at fact that there is xml-based configuration with AOP, so I edited the question to address only annotation of pointcut.

Comment: It's a question of style and brevity. Use constants if you prefer them.

Comment: Question is a bit unclear. Is it about using String constants instead of literals, or about using `@Pointcut` vs just `@Before`?

Comment: How is this an issue of overhead?

Comment: shmosel, using method instead of defining constant is not overhead?

Comment: Thilo, @ Pointcut vs private final String. And Boris Pavlovich has (probably) answered the question. ps: I still don't understand the need to invent the wheel with @ Pointcut if final Strings exist.

Comment: I was pointed at fact that there is xml-based configuration with AOP, so I edited the question to address only annotation of pointcut.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of pointcuts add a level of abstraction/redirection between the advice and the actual join points, improving scalability and separation of concerns:

- In case of refactoring of your program, only the pointcuts need to be adapted, not every advices.
- Pointcuts and advices can be defined separately (for example, the maintainer of a library can provide some pointcuts to the actual user of the library).
- Composition (combination) of pointcuts allows to keep things clear (in your example, you could have defined a `@Pointcut("pointcutMethod() || secondPointcutMethod()")` ).

More details and examples can be found directly in the spring documentation:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts

But as said by Boris Pavlović, it is a matter of style, and you should use what is the most convenient to you.

Comment: One question... (sry for replying so late) pointcutMethod() or secondPointcutMethod() are custom String methods defined in the same class itself? Or they have to be the pointcuts themselves?